# Updating a record when another record is duplicated

Tags: sql

In my table (tbl_emi) there are some values under the record cardno that are repeated, I want the below update query to update only the records that have only one unique cardno in the table. `RecAmt` should be updated with the sum of `extraamt` where the date is the minmum date + the `recamt` where the date is todays date.

```
UPDATE e5
SET RecAmt=
  ( SELECT
     (SELECT sum(extraamt)
      FROM Tbl_Emi e1
      WHERE LastRecDate<(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
        AND e1.CardNo=e.CardNo) +
     (SELECT RecAmt
      FROM Tbl_Emi e2
      WHERE LastRecDate=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
        AND e2.CardNo=e.CardNo)
   FROM Tbl_Emi e
   WHERE e.lastrecdate=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
     AND Status in('N','P')
     AND e.CardNo=e5.CardNo--step 8 manually add the extra amount to the recovery amount
 )
FROM Tbl_Emi e5
WHERE LastRecDate=(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
  AND Status in('N','P')
```

Comment: Please put some effort into your question if you want us to put effort into answering it.

Comment: I changed it, please check

Answer (score 0):

Your query is much too complex for the question that you are asking. I can't fix this query because you don't tell me what it should do or what you're trying to accomplish.

So instead I'll just give you a query that solves the problem that you describe:

Update only those rows for which `cardNo` is unique. I don't know with what to update it (you didn't tell) so I'll just update it with a dummy value:

```
UPDATE Tbl_Emi e SET RecAmt = 1
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM Tbl_Emi
    WHERE e.CardNo = CardNo
    GROUP BY CardNo
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1);
```

Comment: the recamt should be updated the sum of the extraamt where the date is the minmum date + the recamt where the date is tofays date.